# OL OSM get center point of a specific Layer

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, angular-openlayers

I am using Open layer OSM map with Angular to browse countries then states and then cities accordingly. I am able to level up as per selction and adding new layer for each. I am not removing but Just hidding previous layer suppose if someone selected New york from United states then all countries layer will be made hidden and upper layer with NewYark Cities will be visible. Now I need to give user ability to drill back to Upper level. Like double clicking on New York will display back all counties. so to do it when I hide current Layer and show previous layer it shows correctly but I am unable to retrieve its center point. can any one help in it ?

```
this.map.on('singleclick', (event) => {
    // do foreach for each layer  this.MapLevel is each layer number in map
    this['vectorLayer' + this.MapLevel].getFeatures(event.pixel).then((features) => {
        if (!features.length) {
          selection = {};
          return;
        }
        const feature = features[0];
        if (!feature) {
          return;
        }
 this.MapLevel = this.MapLevel + 1;
        this['vectorLayer' + this.MapLevel] = new VectorLayer({
source: new VectorSource({
          url: this.MapSourceURl, // local json file path to retrive Data
          map: this.map,
          format: new GeoJSON(),
          wrapX: false,
          useSpatialIndex: false,
          overlaps: false 
         })}); // layer parameters not pasting here as it has long
        this.map.addLayer(this['vectorLayer' + this.MapLevel]);
        this['vectorLayer'+ this.MapLevel].setVisible(true);
        this['vectorLayer' + (this.MapLevel - 1)].setVisible(false);
      });
      });


// On double click I am trying to show previous layer to downgrade Level in map

this.map.on('dblclick', (event) => {


     this['vectorLayer' + (this.MapLevel - 1)].setVisible(true);
     this['vectorLayer' + (this.MapLevel - 1)].setOpacity(1);
     this.view.animate({center: toLonLat([this.long, this.lati]), zoom : this.view.getZoom() - 1, duration: 2000});
     this.map.removeLayer(this['vectorLayer' + this.MapLevel]);
     this['vectorLayer'+ this.MapLevel].setVisible(false);
    });

But I am not getting correct zoom level of previous layer this so this code is failing.
```

Comment: I am not sure if you are having a code issue or your question is more about how to do it?. If it is related to code, it would be nice that you add it to the question, at least the relevant parts, like how you are getting the feature you want to zoom to (in the example New York polygon).

Comment: @cabesuon I have updated question with code. Kindly have a look now.

Comment: Your idea is, with a click you want to down a level, and double click go up a level, right. There are a couple of things that I don't understand from your code, 1) You have all the layers load in `vectorLayerLevel` variables right?, then why are you updating a source and from what layer? (btw there is something wrong with that part you are declaring type `source :` not assigning `source =`); 2) where are you updating `MapLevel`?; 3) where are you zooming in; 4) you want to go one zoom up or zoom to the feature?

Comment: @cabesuon sorry for the mistake, as I was having large code so missed these few things while adding code here. I have updated above code with these msising points.
regarding point 4: I want to zoom to a specific layer. 

It is case like I have three layers and current zoom level is set up with latest layer. Now when I want to show its previous layer then I need that layer's zoom. saving state will not help in that because we may have multiple layers. Hope I answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this may work,

```
let updateViewExtent = function (pixel, level) {
  this['vectorLayer' + level].getFeatures(event.pixel).then((features) => {
    if (features.length > 0) {
      return;
    }
    const feature = features[0];
    if (!feature) {
      return;
    }
    // zoom to feature clicked (here just first feature)
    this.map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry().getExtent(), {size: this.map.getSize()});
}
this.map.on('singleclick', (event) => {
  // if this is the lower level return
  if (this.MapLevel === LOWERLEVEL) {
    return;
  }
  // zoom to the clicked feature of the level
  updateViewExtent(event.pixel, this.MapLevel);
  // update map level and layers visibility
  this['vectorLayer' + this.MapLevel].setVisible(false);
  this.MapLevel += 1;
  this['vectorLayer' + this.MapLevel].setVisible(true);
});
this.map.on('dblclick', (event) => {
  // if this is the upper level return
  if (this.MapLevel === UPPERLEVEL) {
    return;
  }
  // zoom to the clicked feature of the upper level
  updateViewExtent(event.pixel, this.MapLevel - 1);
  // update map level and layers visibility
  this['vectorLayer' + this.MapLevel].setVisible(false);
  this.MapLevel -= 1;
  this['vectorLayer' + this.MapLevel].setVisible(true);
});
```

I use a function to zoom desire extent, in this case the clicked feature. Actually it could happen that is more than a feature, you could zoom to extended extent. If you actually want to zoom to the layer extent on double click then instead of calling the function just use this,

```
// zoom upper layer extent
this.map.getView().fit(
  this['vectorLayer' + (this.MapLevel - 1)].getSource().getExtent(),
  {size: this.map.getSize()}
);
```

Lastly, you may need to cancel the default behavior of the map on double click (zoom in one level).

Comment: as I have cleared question requirements. kindly remove downvote from it if possible.